# how to make thread safe raycasting in C++?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, raycasting

i am implementing simple plane raycasting in c++ and i used OpenMP for multithreading.
here is the function that goes through all pixels and computes intersections:

```
 #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
 for (int x = 0; x < camera_.GetWidth(); x++)
 {
    for (uint32_t y = 0; y < camera_.GetHeight(); y++)
    {
      Ray ray(camera_.GetPosition());
      ray.SetDirection(GetDirection(glm::vec2((2.0f * x) / camera_.GetWidth() - 1.0f, (2.0f * y) / camera_.GetHeight() - 1.0f)));

      cogs::Color3f temp = cogs::Color3f(0, 0, 0);

      for (uint16_t p = 0; p < models_.size(); p++)
      {
        //mutex.lock();
        if (models_.at(p)->Intersection(ray))
        {
          ray.SetParamT(models_.at(p)->GetDistanceT());
          temp = models_.at(p)->GetColor() * (camera_.GetLightEnergy() / ray.GetParamT());
        }
        //mutex.unlock();
      }
      renderer.SetPixel(x, y, temp );
    }
  }  


bool Plane::Intersection(Ray &ray)
{

  float dot = glm::dot(ray.GetDirection(), normal_);

  if (dot == 0.0f)
  {
    return false;
  }

  float t = glm::dot(reference_ - ray.GetOrigin(), normal_) / dot;

  if (t <= 0.0001 || t > ray.GetParamT())
  {
    return false;
  }

  SetDistanceT(t);

  return true;
}
```

here is the result:
[image: raycast]

as you can see some of the pixels are mixed up, but if i uncomment mutex lock and unlock from this code, then results is correct, but it takes even longer to compute than not using pragma omp

any idea how could i make this more thread safe? when i started, almost half of the pixels were mixed up, then in my custom classes i added every variable as private and create getters and setters, which helped, but its still not completely correct

EDIT: updated code based on @Jérôme Richard advise and added code for intersection

Comment: Have you tried locking/unlocking outside the `for`?

Comment: I guess that your GetXXX methods do not change mutable attributes, is it true ?
Also why do you do `models_.at(p)->SetDistanceT(TMAX)` ? Is TMAX a constant ?
@StephenNewell putting locking/unlocking outside the `for` will not provide any parallel speed-up since the most intensive computation part is likely to be located in the loop itself.

Comment: @StephenNewell yes, that gives also correct result but its even longer than without omp

Comment: @JérômeRichard no Get methods doesnt change any attributes and yes TMAX is constant and it is not necessary to set here, ill edit the code

Comment: @mereth Ok, check the code still have the same problem without the line `models_.at(p)->SetDistanceT(TMAX)` because I think this is what cause your issue. Also note that putting `num_threads(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())` is not needed as OpenMP use the maximum number of threads by default, except if you manually set the variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` (which is very convenient, especially to debug codes). Also you can use the `collapse(2)` clause to scale better on systems with many cores.

Comment: @JérômeRichard okay so it improved the result, but its still not 100%, on image in the question there are like 20 wrong pixels, now it looks like i get max 2-3 wrong pixel colors

Comment: I advise you to use a temporary variable for the color and set the (x,y) pixel of the `renderer` only at the end of your (x,y) loop so that in theory threads only reads things during the computation and only write things at the end (it should be safer and faster). If the `Intersection` method do not change internal attributes nor `GetXXX`, the race condition you observe is theoretically not possible.

Comment: i used temp variable for color, but it's still giving me wrong result sometimes(like every other run looks correct), i think i might be doing something wrong in intersection, i added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a method called `bool Plane::Intersect(Ray &)` that *mutates the Plane object* in addition to determining whether there is an intersection, and then later pulling the result of this mutation out of the `Plane` object while hoping it wasn't changed in another thread in the meantime, is likely your problem (or at least one of them), and moreover is just not great software engineering.

I'd recommend getting rid of the whole `SetDistanceT` / `GetDistanceT` functionality entirely.  Just return the distance from the method that checks intersections directly, and make that method `const` in both its argument and its instance.

(How do you handle the case where `dot` is zero?  You could either return `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()` in that case, or you could have the method return something like a `std::pair<bool, double>`, or a custom struct, or...)

**EDIT:** And while you're at it, I'd declare this method as `float Intersect(const Ray &) const` after you fix it, so that the compiler *enforces* that it doesn't mutate the ray or the the plane.  (The second `const` there says that the method doesn't mutate the instance it's called on, in this case the plane you're intersecting with.)

Comment: yes setting and getting distance was the problem. changed it that instead of false is returns infinity and instead of true it returns the distance. thank you